# How to include RPS in locust report

Tags: locust

I noticed if the locust is run in no-web mode and csv stats is downloaded than there is no column for RPS. Is there any way to include RPS? Also, i wanted to generate a PDF/HTML report for locust .Is there any way to do the same? I have searched internet and found no solution for the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After many hours of research i found the perfect way to create a report for my locust tests.
[Generate intuitive Locust.io reports with Jtl Reporter](https://medium.com/@novyludek/generate-intuitive-locust-io-reports-with-jtl-reporter-c40c71913d64)
Posting in hope it will help others as well who are looking for the similar answer.

Also, from the locust we ui we now have a option to download report. I'm using latest version of locust 1.4.1